# can't connect Mysql to NetBeans(in windows os)

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, classnotfoundexception, mysql-connector

I'm having problem connecting MySQL to Java. I haven't found a driver for windows and was told to choose platform independent.
 I'm using NetBeans ide 8.2 and MySQL server 8.0.13 and MySQL Workbench 8.0.13 I've tried to download older versions of drivers to see if it would work but it's just the same result:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

the records aren't displayed in the output when I run
am I missing something? do I have to do something other than adding the driver to libraries in NetBeans and writing the connection code? please help me I'm new to this and I need help. Thank you
[this is the table in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW0cT.png)
[this is the connection code in NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qqco.png)

Comment: We cannot help you like this. Are you talking about the mysql driver for java? Where is your code? What is your exception? What kind of answer do you expect to your question like this?

Comment: I've added the photos just now

Comment: That does look ok. The class name is correct for 8.0.13, it used to be in a different package in previous driver versions. But it doesnt seem to be in your classpath. Can you remove the ``Class.forName`` line and see if it works without it? AFAIK checking for the class manually hasnt been necessary for years.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *f1sh* that your code looks OK, and also that you don't need the `Class.forName()` line in your code. I also agree that option *Platform Independent* is the correct choice of operating system for Windows when downloading the driver.

However, your screenshot unfortunately doesn't show the file extension of the driver that you added under the **Libraries** node. Can you confirm that the file's extension is **jar**, not **zip** or **tar**?

Downloading the MySQL driver creates a **zip** or **tar** file (depending on which option you picked), but you have to unzip that to access the actual driver named **mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar**, and that is the file you must add to your project:

[image: driverJar]

If I include the `Class.forName()` call, and add the **zip** instead of the **jar** to to a simple test project I get exactly the same error as you in NetBeans:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at jdbcselecttest.JdbcSelectTest.dbQuery(JdbcSelectTest.java:31)
    at jdbcselecttest.JdbcSelectTest.main(JdbcSelectTest.java:25)
C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

It's worth noting that without the `Class.forName()` call the error changes to this:

```
run:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop?useSSL=false
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at jdbcselecttest.JdbcSelectTest.dbQuery(JdbcSelectTest.java:32)
    at jdbcselecttest.JdbcSelectTest.main(JdbcSelectTest.java:25)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And if I remove the **zip** file, and add the **jar**, file everything works.

If you are already correctly using the **jar** file then there are further options to explore, but that seems like the mostly likely cause of your problem.

Comment: I already put the jar file in the libraries.i went to ask for my problem and i was told i have to add an odbc jar too? I don't know where to find it.i don't know if i'm even doing right..i feel lost.now im asking to borrow a mac pc to redo the project there.thanks anyway..@skomisa